# ActionBarSherlock MenuItem actionLayout issue

Tags: java, android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I'm displaying in the ActionBar a Button where a Text is in it.

This is the menu item:

```
   <item
          android:id="@+id/action_commentview"
           android:showAsAction="always"
           android:actionLayout="@layout/menuitem_commentcounter"
           android:title="Comments"/>
```

And this is the menuitem_commentcounter layout:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="43dp"
       android:layout_height="25dp"
       android:id="@+id/commentCounterLayout"
       android:clickable="true"
       >

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="31dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:clickable="false"
           android:contentDescription="rating up"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_comment" />



       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_commentCounter"
           android:layout_width="22dp"
           android:layout_height="13dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
           android:includeFontPadding="false"
           android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
           android:clickable="false"
           android:linksClickable="false"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:lines="1"
           android:textAlignment="center"
           android:textColor="@color/white"
           android:background="@color/black"
           android:textSize="12sp"
           android:typeface="sans" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

On my devices Api level >= 11, there is all ok. On my devices Api Level < 11 the margin-top at the tv_commentCounter TextView doesn't work. After some testing I detected, that setting the margin-top to 15dip, also on < 11 Level Devices works (But then on API Level => 11 it doesn't).

Did I something wrong, because it's not normal that I need to add 11dip if API Level is < 11.

Thanks

Comment: A good icon is simple graphic. Do you really need the TextView? If you do, maybe consider draw the icon with the text instead of layout it.

Comment: When generating the menu Icon on opening, the performance is not good. I solved it by set a custom view to the entire ActionBar, there the topMargin works like expected.